# In spark and scala, how to convert or map a dataframe to specific columns info?

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, dataframe

Scala.
Spark.
intellij IDEA.

I have a dataframe (multiple rows, multiple columns) from CSV file.
And I want it maps to another specific column info.
I think scala class (not case class, because columns count > 22) or `map()`.....

But I don't know how to convert them.

Example

a dataframe from CSV file.

```
----------------------
| No  |  price| name |
----------------------
|  1  |  100  |  "A" |
----------------------
|  2  |  200  |  "B" |
----------------------
```

another specific columns info.

```
 => {product_id, product_name, seller}
```

First, `product_id` is mapping to 'No'.
Second, `product_name` is mapping to 'name'.
Third, `seller` is `null` or ""(empty string).

So, finally, I want a dataframe that have another columns info.

```
-----------------------------------------
| product_id  |  product_name  | seller |
-----------------------------------------
|      1      |       "A"      |        |
-----------------------------------------
|      2      |       "B"      |        |
-----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a dataframe (eg. old_df) :

```
val new_df=old_df.withColumnRenamed("No","product_id").
                  withColumnRenamed("name","product_name").
                  drop("price").
                  withColumn("seller", ... )
```

Comment: Thanks. WillemM.

But, old_table columns count is 130.
and new_table columns count is 40.
and overlapped columns count is 20.

In this situation, withColumnRenamed() and drop() functions are efficient?

Comment: Is there another way to map old_table(column count:130)  and new_table(column count:40)?
for example, using class or map() function?

Comment: If it's pretty straight-forward, and it's just the number of columns that 'scares' you, how about writing a little python script that generates code similar to above from a old->new mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your CSV file is "products.csv",

First you have to load it in spark, you can do that using

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
     .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
     .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
     .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
     .load("cars.csv")
```

Once the data is loaded you will have all the column names in the dataframe df. As you mentioned your column name will be "No","Price","Name".

To change the name of the column you just have to use withColumnRenamed api of dataframe.

```
val renamedDf = df.withColumnRenamed("No","product_id").
   withColumnRenames("name","product_name")
```

Your renamedDf will have the name of the column as you have assigned.